# SVG 1.1 as mask with CSS

Tags: css, svg, mask, adobe-illustrator

I can't mask my image to my Illustrator SVG, what did I do wrong here?

```css
.contato .tinypic .svgmask-img{
    -webkit-mask: url(#svgmask);
}
```

```html
<img class="svgmask-img img-responsive" src="http://il7.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/5241152/thumb/1.jpg">

 <svg version="1.1" id="svgmask" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="enable-background:new 0 0 250 250;" xml:space="preserve">
 <path d="M112,235.6l-92.9-67.5c-7.7-5.6-11-15.6-8-24.7L46.6,34.2c3-9.1,11.4-15.2,21-15.2h114.9c9.6,0,18,6.2,21,15.2l35.5,109.3
    c3,9.1-0.3,19.1-8,24.7L138,235.6C130.2,241.3,119.8,241.3,112,235.6z"/>
 </svg>
```

I created that SVG and added some jQuery animations to the SVG element for the mouseover and mouseout events so I can't use another method to mask because I don't want to apply the same animation to my image, only to the mask.

Comment: You want to know why Illustrator doesn't recognise webkit specific CSS?

Comment: What does the html surrounding the `img` tag look like? If one of the parent elements doesn't have the `.contato` and `.tinypic` classes then that css isn't going to work.

Comment: Everything is correct

`<div id="contato" class="contato">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mydetails-small">
<div class="col-xs-4 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg tinypic">
<img class="svgmask-img img-responsive" src="">`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're updating the SVG you could try using `clip-path` instead of `-webkit-mask`. It does involve making some tweaks to the SVG code, but it works in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path).

```css
.contato .tinypic .svgmask-img {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgmask);
          clip-path: url(#svgmask);
}
```

```html
<div id="contato" class="contato">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 mydetails-small">
      <div class="col-xs-4 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg tinypic">
        <img class="svgmask-img img-responsive" src="http://il7.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/5241152/thumb/1.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgmask"> // Path and id moved to defs
      <path d="M112,235.6l-92.9-67.5c-7.7-5.6-11-15.6-8-24.7L46.6,34.2c3-9.1,11.4-15.2,21-15.2h114.9c9.6,0,18,6.2,21,15.2l35.5,109.3
        c3,9.1-0.3,19.1-8,24.7L138,235.6C130.2,241.3,119.8,241.3,112,235.6z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot I had autoprefixer running. I've updated the css with the webkit-specific rule.  [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/5dw1vL3k/)

Comment: Im using bootstrap img-responsive tag on image to make it responsive but svg mask ins't, do you know how to make svg mask responsive on bootstrap?

Comment: The `img-responsive` tag will be applied to the un-clipped image. Because the svg is smaller than the image, and is a fixed size, it won't fill the space. You'll need to re-export the svg from Illustrator with the responsive option ticked, so that it will resize, then set the width to be 100%.
See here for info on exporting a responsive svg: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/responsive-svg-files-in-illustrator.html?go=21334